# How to get image URL of the product image field in Drupal Commerce

Tags: entities, commerce

I'm stil pretty new to Drupal Commerce and I've run into a small issue with something that has worked for me in the past. I'm working on a custom Product Display node template and I'm wanting to get just the URL of the image in the image field. Right now I'm rendering the image with:

```
<?php print render($content['product:field_image']); ?>
```

In the past I have generated just the image field URL with the following code:

```
<?php echo file_create_url($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>
```

However, modifying that to call product:field_image results in a total page error. Does anyone know the proper syntax to generate just the URL of the product image field?

Comment: Brad, did you find an answer to your question? I would love to know how you modified your code to make it work as I have the same issue. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you checked Image URL Formatter module? [https://drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter] Perhaps it's easiest that way.